# Remove all fields of a struct at a specific index

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

If I have a struct such as:

```
myStruct = struct('a',[1,2,3],'b',[1,2,3],'c',[1,2,3])
```

...And I wanted to remove the second element of every field, I would do the following:

```
myStruct.a(2) = [];
myStruct.b(2) = [];
myStruct.c(2) = [];
```

Is there a simpler way of performing this operation, i.e. one that doesn't involve writing out each field name manually? I have structs that may inherit several different fields in different circumstances, so I can never know explicitly which fields will be present in order to hard-code it. And even if I *did* know, it can take up several lines!

Note: I am aware that it is possible to arrange structs in the format of `myStruct(2).a`, but I prefer the format `myStruct.a(2)` as it allows me to add fields to the struct one-at-a-time, depending on the needs of the specific program I'm running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`structfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to apply an anonymous function to each field:

```
myStruct = structfun(@(x) x([1 3:end]), myStruct, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware for `fieldnames` and dynamic fieldnames?

```
fnames = fieldnames ( myStruct )
for ii=1:length(fnames)
   myStruct.(fnames{ii})(2) = [];
end
```